# How to iterate over properties of Powershell instance

Tags: powershell

How can I iterate over the properties of the current instance from a method defined on the same instance. To illustrate what I mean see the example below.

```
Class Foo {

    [String] $Bar = "Cheese";
    [String] $Quux = "Cake";

    [Void] List (){

       ForEach($Prop in $This){
        Write-Host $This.Name
       }

    }

}

$Foo = [Foo]::New()
$Foo.List()
```

This does not work as expected as nothing is output to the console. I'd just like to understand why this doesn't work and what I would need to do to get it to print out the name and value of Bar and Quux.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the properties of `$This` and print them to get what you need.

```
Class Foo {
     [String] $bar = "Cheese";
     [String] $Quux = "Cake";

    [Void] List() 
    {
        foreach($var in $This.PSObject.Properties) 
        {
            write-host $var.Name
        }
    }
}

$Foo = [Foo]::New()
$Foo.List()
```

**Output**

```
bar
Quux
```

[PropertyInfo details can be found here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.management.automation.pspropertyinfo?view=pscore-6.2.0#properties)